Last card doesn't stack using position sticky as expected
I trying to create stacking cards effect using position: sticky.
All cards have increment of +20px offset.
Every card stacks except for the last. I should be stacked at 120px like others did while scrolling.
I've set top: 120px but for some reason it doesn't sticky, instead it just overlaps and hide others underneath it.
Kindly, explain when answering. I'm learning this sticky feature.


.spacer {
  height: 120vh;
  background: red;
}

.stack-cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  gap: 20px;
  
  margin-block: 40px;
}

.stack-card {
  position: sticky;

  top: 20px;

  padding: 24px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  
  color: #52225e;
  background: #c1b0e4;
}

.stack-card:nth-child(2) {
  top: 40px;

  color: #52225e;
  background: #f682a5;
}

.stack-card:nth-child(3) {
  top: 60px;

  color: #1c471f;
  background: #c9da8f;
}

.stack-card:nth-child(4) {
  top: 80px;

  color: #4a411e;
  background: #fedf6f;
}

.stack-card:nth-child(5) {
  top: 100px;

  color: #582614;
  background: #f9a474;
}

.stack-card:nth-child(6) {
  top: 120px;

  color: #184363;
  background: #b8cedc;
}
<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="stack-cards">
  <div class="stack-card">
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias, excepturi.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="stack-card">
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias, excepturi.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="stack-card">
    <h2>Heading 3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias, excepturi.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="stack-card">
    <h2>Heading 4</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias, excepturi.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="stack-card">
    <h2>Heading 5</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias, excepturi.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="stack-card">
    <h2>Heading 6</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias, excepturi.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>




The last one doesn't "stick" like the others do, because there is no more content in .stack-cards after this. It has no reason to stick, because at that point you are done with scrolling over .stack-cards, and the whole element will be allowed to move out of the top of the viewport at this point.

add the spacer inside stack-cards
